# Angular ng-template : Access method of the container template from within the invoked template?

Tags: angular

I have an originator template that refers the template its rendering. I have a method in the originating template which I want invoked in the child template (not sublassing the origin template component.ts in the reference component.ts because of some DI related reasons). How would I go about this?

**originator.component.ts**

```
export class OriginatorComponent implements OnInit {
.....
    execute() {
        // Execute some code
    }

    retrieve() {
        // Execute some code
    }
}
```

**originator.component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="test === 'abc'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="abcdef"></ng-container>

    <ng-template #abcdef>
      <foo-template></foo-template>
    </ng-template>
```

**foo.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo-component',
    templateUrl: './foo-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./foo-component.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
.....
    someMethod1() {
        execute();    // <--- HOW DO I DO THIS? EXECUTE Originating templates method?
    }

    someMethod2() {
        retrieve();    // <--- HOW DO I DO THIS? EXECUTE Originating templates method?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest not trying to invoke the parent method in the child. Consider using an event emitter to communicate to the parent from the child https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event.

Originator Component:

```
export class OriginatorComponent implements OnInit {
    .....
    onExecute() {
        // Execute some code
    }
}
```

Originator Component Template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="test === 'abc'">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="abcdef"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #abcdef>
  <foo-template (execute)="onExecute()" ></foo-template>
</ng-template>
```

Foo Component

```
@Component({
   selector: 'foo-component',
   templateUrl: './foo-component.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./foo-component.component.scss']
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() execute = new EventEmitter();
    .....
    someMethod() {
        this.execute.emit(); // you can send any variable to parent
    }
}
```

When `this.execute.emit();` is fired, your handler in your parent element (`onExecute`) will be called.

**EDIT**

Here is a stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1h1rdz)

Comment: Interesting.I do have more than one method though in the parent component `execute()` `retrieve()` . can one pass more than one emitter via this approach?

Comment: added a stackblitz demo, check the console to see the emits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1h1rdz

Answer (score -1):

```html
<ng-template #abcdef>
    <foo-component></foo-component>
</ng-template>
```

and in your component file use

```js
@ViewChild(FooComponent  ) ref: FooComponent;
```

In `ngAfterViewInit() { this.ref.someMethod1(); }` is called.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'someMethod' of undefined)